# Why is Scipy getting different answers for the eigenvalues of this matrix?

Tags: python, scipy

In Scipy, I have a 7x7 matrix that has some entries as large as 10^22.

```
[[7.87720699e+21 5.81984000e+12 4.06283195e+18 1.36914426e+15
  6.84296262e+21 1.18920842e+20 2.30532710e+21]
 [5.81984000e+12 6.32869618e+03 3.12159108e+09 8.49240505e+05
  5.05790011e+12 8.25020510e+10 1.71012096e+12]
 [4.06283195e+18 3.12159108e+09 2.10517370e+15 6.90360153e+11
  3.52958137e+18 6.08623401e+16 1.18959479e+18]
 [1.36914426e+15 8.49240505e+05 6.90360153e+11 2.68568446e+08
  1.18907574e+15 2.15022766e+13 3.99729760e+14]
 [6.84296262e+21 5.05790011e+12 3.52958137e+18 1.18907574e+15
  5.94451366e+21 1.03298010e+20 2.00265814e+21]
 [1.18920842e+20 8.25020510e+10 6.08623401e+16 2.15022766e+13
  1.03298010e+20 1.81926760e+18 3.47747090e+19]
 [2.30532710e+21 1.71012096e+12 1.18959479e+18 3.99729760e+14
  2.00265814e+21 3.47747090e+19 6.74706499e+20]]
```

When I call `spicy.linalg.eigvalsh` on it, I get

```
scipy.linalg.eigvalsh(square_matrix)
array([-1.65239967e+05,  3.55247340e+04,  2.64944833e+06,  2.26542682e+09,\n        2.01743752e+14,  5.56910661e+16,  1.44981926e+22])
```

That's not good, because the matrix is symmetric positive semidefinite (it's of the form AA^T), so it should have all non-negative eigenvalues. And when I ask it for only the least eigenvalue, it gets quite a different answer than it did last time.

```
scipy.linalg.eigvalsh(square_matrix, eigvals = (0,0))
array([-464577.85826165])
```

What's going on here? Is it just that the numbers are so large that it's causing huge errors in the calculation?

Thanks for the help, I'm somewhat new to numerical experiments like this.

**Edit:** Here's another matrix, posted as a list:

```
[[178484429459288.62, 1.262534539362581e+16, 5756113437609551.0, 1.5274842899247696e+17, 6343247145.960138, 3119899812227.452, 2.6847705451184886e+17], [1.262534539362581e+16, 9.311154944318847e+17, 4.25182007604871e+17, 1.0968899948471126e+19, 418362473621.39294, 236566750583994.28, 1.929426966567391e+19], [5756113437609551.0, 4.25182007604871e+17, 1.9416578714719302e+17, 5.00372260140452e+18, 190262613997.92053, 108142802848362.1, 8.801791711005543e+18], [1.5274842899247696e+17, 1.0968899948471126e+19, 5.00372260140452e+18, 1.3144272477543575e+20, 5288261203200.205, 2737268307603631.5, 2.3109381789197917e+20], [6343247145.960138, 418362473621.39294, 190262613997.92053, 5288261203200.205, 258730.2206841113, 99079200.39025305, 9282686524313.389], [3119899812227.452, 236566750583994.28, 108142802848362.1, 2737268307603631.5, 99079200.39025305, 61292039604.753365, 4817296126969346.0], [2.6847705451184886e+17, 1.929426966567391e+19, 8.801791711005543e+18, 2.3109381789197917e+20, 9282686524313.389, 4817296126969346.0, 4.0629951073761985e+20]]

scipy.linalg.eigvalsh(square_matrix, eigvals = (0,0))
> array([-9362.07065027])

scipy.linalg.eigvalsh(square_matrix)
> array([3.04005337e+01, 1.06920150e+04, 9.94140064e+06, 3.42415026e+09,\n       2.27074109e+13, 1.99821497e+16, 5.38847690e+20])
```

I've confirmed that I'm in Scipy 1.1.0. These are gotten during debugging in the middle of a script, if that makes a difference. Using VS Code as an IDE.

Comment: Could you add the matrix as a list? It would make it easier for copy and pasting.

Comment: In SciPy 1.1.0, I get `[ -9.24542595e+09,  -6.96900398e+05,   2.83573265e+05, 9.47167568e+11,   2.00584446e+14,   5.56891986e+16,
1.44981926e+22])` for the former and `array([ -9.24633189e+09])` for the latter.

Comment: @user6655984 I have SciPy 1.1.0 also. But I'm doing this in debug mode, if that makes any difference.

Comment: @Wade Added another (hard to get the first, because it's generated randomly)

Comment: Considering that the entries go up to `10^22`, an absolute error of size `10^10` when computing eigenvalues is not large. Perhaps one of true eigenvalues is close to 0, and a computational error makes it negative. Looks like nothing is out of ordinary. Why are you doing this, anyway? if you know the matrix is `AA^T`, look for the singular values of `A^T` directly.

Comment: @user6655984 Yes, that seems like a better idea. I'm trying to estimate the condition number of AA^T, where A is a Vandermonde matrix. (AA^T is the Hessian when one does polynomial interpolation.)

Comment: Using MatLab with the original matrix, I get: [-9245435594.58112 130.775876839429 283656.696927059 947166839083.844 200584445132152 5.56891985501969e+16 1.44981926310530e+22], this is basically the same as when I run the same command as your original post, which means that they are using the same algorithm. Since the numbers are so large there must be very large round-off error present. Note: I'm using python 3.6.6, scipy 1.1.0

Answer (score 1):

The entries of a matrix go up to `1e22` but its smallest eigenvalue is likely to be a lot smaller, maybe 1000 or so. When performing complex computations with double-precision numbers (`1e-16` relative error at each step), especially iterative computations for approximate eigenvalues, it's not surprising to get the relative error of size `1e-12`. In absolute terms it becomes `1e10` and that completely dwarfs the smallest eigenvalue, and can easily make it negative.

The search for k smallest or largest eigenvalues is a different task: SciPy does not just compute all eigenvalues and truncates the  output. In the [source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.1.0/scipy/linalg/decomp.py#L430) one can see different calls to LAPACK-based code depending on the presence of `eigvals` parameter, and I'm sure the parameter makes a difference inside LAPACK as well. All this means that the random errors you get may well be different depending on the parameter `eigvals`.

> I'm trying to estimate the condition number

I suggest using [`np.linalg.cond`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.cond.html) for that.

And in general it's better to deal with the singular values of A than with the eigenvalues of A multiplied by its transpose (the condition number [gets nearly squared](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1528/condition-number-of-aa-and-aa-formulations)).